# SPARQL query on DbPedia

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, dbpedia

my problem is that, I need to find out about animal  sounds (Dogs - bark, woof, Cat - mew, purr ..)
(I have a list of animal which I need)

Thought me that I could find out from DbPedia using SPARQL query. Do you think such a thing possible? Alternatively, you know how such a query might look like? (I do not really understand SPARQL, RDF etc)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this sort of data from ConceptNet:

- http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/web/c/en/bark
- http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/web/c/en/meow
- http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/web/c/en/purr

Comment: Someone has to setup a SPARQL endpoint for conceptnet5 ....

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible using DBPedia alone. For example, here is the information DBPedia has about dogs:

http://dbpedia.org/page/Dog

As you can see, there is no info in there about the sound that dogs make. So you would not be able to retrieve this kind of information using a SPARQL query on DBPedia - you would need another source of linked data. Though admittedly I find it unlikely that a source with the information you need is available for public use (then again, it's the Internet, stranger things have been published).